# Why are malloc hooks unsafe with pthreads?

Tags: c, pthreads, malloc, glibc, ld-preload

I am trying to build a wrapper for `malloc` and wondering whether `malloc` hooks would be thread-safe under pthreads.

Comment: That depends on whether the functions invoked by the `malloc` hooks are thread-safe, doesn't it?  The core code in `malloc()` has to be thread-safe; it can't control whether the code called for the hooks are thread-safe, but the code so written should be.

Comment: Are you wrapping `malloc` using LD_PRELOAD tricks, as per tags and question text, or are you using the `__malloc_hook` stuff from glibc?

Comment: I am using __malloc_hook fomr glibc

Answer (score 3):

`__malloc_hook` is called right after entering `__libc_malloc` in [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c#L3011):

```
void *
__libc_malloc (size_t bytes)
{
  mstate ar_ptr;
  void *victim;

  void *(*hook) (size_t, const void *)
    = atomic_forced_read (__malloc_hook);
  if (__builtin_expect (hook != NULL, 0))
    return (*hook)(bytes, RETURN_ADDRESS (0));
```

while the thread locking is implemented in `__libc_malloc` 20 lines below, in [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c#L3039):

```
  if (SINGLE_THREAD_P)
    {
      victim = _int_malloc (&main_arena, bytes);
      assert (!victim || chunk_is_mmapped (mem2chunk (victim)) ||
          &main_arena == arena_for_chunk (mem2chunk (victim)));
      return victim;
    }

  arena_get (ar_ptr, bytes);
```

`arena_get` is constructing the arena for the thread or choosing the arena and locking the arena, declared [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/arena.c#L105).

So when designing your own `__malloc_hook` the developer is responsible for everything, including threads locking (if needed).

Comment: And the problem is that if you want to *wrap* the existing malloc, you cannot do so because once you disable the hooks, other threads will no longer call into your wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use them anyways; they're deprecated.  See the "Notes" section of any recent copy of [`the malloc_hook(3) man page`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/__malloc_hook):

> The use of these hook functions is not safe in multithreaded programs, and they are now deprecated. Programmers should instead preempt calls to the relevant functions by defining and exporting functions such as "malloc" and "free".